# JSLint error: Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function

Tags: jquery, jslint, jshint

How can i make this code jsLint Happy ?

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
  //some code 
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

It advises me to write it this way ? Will there be any difference ? What do i do ?

```
(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
  //some code 
}( jQuery, window, document ));
```

Comment: No, there's no difference. JSLint can be overly picky about coding styles, and this is one of those cases. Putting the function invocation parens inside the function surrounding parens has zero impact on this code. I always turn off this setting when using JSLint (among others)

Comment: How can i turn off this check in JSLint  ?

Comment: also defensive semicolon before function , how i can turn it off using lint ? as well

Comment: Ah, that's right, I forgot it doesn't let you turn that setting off. These are both cases where jslint is overly opinionated. I'd recommend jshint.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm copying my answer from the next question in the JSLint stack.  Here's why Crockford says that the second way is better.

From http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

> When a function is to be invoked immediately, the entire invocation
>   expression should be wrapped in parens so that it is clear that the
>   value being produced is the result of the function and not the
>   function itself.

To expand a little, JavaScript isn't, as we know, a strongly typed language.  It's not uncommon to push a `function` into a variable, and, in fact, it could be more common to push a function into a `var` than a value from an immediately invoked anonymous function.

So it's worth having a little syntactic sugar in your code to show when you're *invoking* rather than setting a reference to a function.

Don't get bogged down by those that complain that it's impossible to separate [Douglas Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford)'s opinions from JSLint. They're right, and that's good!

In a big enough project, why would you *have* to disagree with him?  I'm never seen Crockford require something that's objectively wrong.  All of the rules in JSLint are *arguably* good ones, and standardization of code in shared projects is often A Very Good Thing.  He's teaching you good (!bad?) habits for free.  It's worth playing along.

(The leading semi-colon, I see where you're going -- defensive is good.  But if everyone used JSLint...  I still feel your pain there a little.)