# About JSLint behaviour

Tags: javascript, jslint

Could someone please explain why does JSLint accept this style:

```
(function () { /* .... */ }());
```

but dislikes this one:

```
(function () { /* .... */ })();
```

I'm aware that JSLint has some extremely strict regulations, but at least most of those rules have (allegedly) some kind of a purpose. I just cannot figure out of what this purpose is in this particular case.

(I'm not trying to argue here, I'm just trying to understand the reason.)

Comment: Dislikes? What is the error it gives?

Comment: http://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function/

Comment: A summary of the link that @PaoloMoretti put in their comment: `<sarcasm>`the creator of JSLint is a spiteful person that doesn't like adding options to it and wants everybody to code the same way that they do in cases where it really makes absolutely no difference.`</sarcasm>`

Comment: JSLint is literally the embodiment of Douglas Crockford's opinions about the proper ways to write JavaScript code. He does have a rationale for every little nitpicky thing, but at the end of the day it's still just his opinion.

Comment: Just watch this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGArABpLy0k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is almost exactly the same question as the [most recent jslint-tagged question before this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474275/jslint-error-move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function), which also asks about defensive leading semi-colons.  Remember to search within your tags before asking!

That said, let's give a free pass -- the other question doesn't have an accepted answer, so here you go.  ;^)  (That said, we should close one of them as a dupe.)

Here's why Crockford says that the second version is better.

From http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

> When a function is to be invoked immediately, the entire invocation
>   expression should be wrapped in parens so that it is clear that the
>   value being produced is the result of the function and not the
>   function itself.

To expand a little, JavaScript isn't, as we know, a strongly typed language.  It's not uncommon to push a `function` into a variable, and, in fact, it could be more common to push a function into a `var` than a value from an immediately invoked anonymous function.

```
var whatAmI = function () { return 5; };    // You're a function!
```

vs.

```
var whatAmI = (function () { return 5;}()); // You're the number 5!
```

So it's worth having a little syntactic sugar in your code to show clearly when you're *invoking* rather than setting a reference to a function.

Don't get bogged down by those that complain that it's hard^H^H^H^H^H impossible to separate [Douglas Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford)'s opinions from JSLint. They're right, and that's good!

In a big enough project, why would you *have* to disagree with him?  I'm never seen Crockford require something that's objectively wrong.  All of the rules in JSLint are *arguably* good ones, and standardization of code in shared projects is often A Very Good Thing.  He's teaching you good (!bad?) habits for free.  It's worth playing along.